# Xamarin.Forms inflate view in code and pass parameter

Tags: xamarin.forms

I set up multiple different views that I can inflate from xaml like so:

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="grid_someelsesprofile_currentproducts">
                        <!-- ID = 4 for profile-->
                             <views:CV_AllAdsRes>
                                 <x:Arguments >
                                <x:Int32>4</x:Int32>
                                 </x:Arguments>
                             </views:CV_AllAdsRes>
                        </Grid>
```

I even pass a parameter, in this case an int with the value of 4.

Now I need to be able to inflate this also but from code and also pass the parameter and add this view to the grid. So basically all I am doing from above only from code basis.

CV_AllAdsRes is a contentview file.

How would that translate?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually super easy:

load the class holding the view and logic:

```
        var xy = new CV_AllAdsRes(4, userID);
```

Then add class to grid.children method:

```
        grid_someelsesprofile_currentproducts.Children.Add(xy);
```